# Why were there fewer flagging options?

Tags: support, flagging

Recently, I tried to flag a question but there were fewer flagging options than usual. What could be the reason for this?

[image: Question flag dialog with only "spam", "offensive" and "other" options]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that you were trying to flag a question that was already closed. In these cases it doesn't make sense to flag it for closure, so these options are removed ("duplicate" and "should be closed for another reason). Also, [the "very low quality" flag option is removed from questions that are on-hold/closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186764/214632).